# Concerned about subscribing twice with the same code and then unsubscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Lets say I have a function like below that gets called by a button click in my component.

1. What happens if I click my button twice to the first and second subscriptions?
2. What happens if I click my button twice and then unsubscribe `mySub` in my ngOnDestroy()?
3. If the function has potential to be called twice, should I add logic in `myFunction()` to unsubscribe from my first subscription before subscribing again?

```
mySub: Subscription;

myFunction(){

    this.mySub = this.myService.getSomeData(this.data).subscribe({
        next: (val) => { 
            //stuff
        },
        error: (e) => { 
            //more stuff
        }
    });

}
```

I'm thinking that if there's potential for a subscription to be executed twice then I should unsubscribe before making another subscription.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong here but I believe...

1. You will have 2 subscriptions
2. Only the current instance of `mySub` will be unsubscribed

3....

Instead, I would declare a subject in the component and `next` it when the button is clicked. In your `ngOnInit` subscribe to the that subject and mergeMap it to the getSomeData observable. Something like this:

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private mySubj = new Subject<void>()
  private sub: Subscription | null = null
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.mySubj.pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.myService.getSomeData
    ).subscribe(() => {
       // Do the thing 
    })
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.mySubj.next()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub?.unsubscribe()
}
```

I'm on mobile so please excuse any typos. Will edit if pointed out

Comment: if you use `Subject<void>` you don't need to pass a value when calling `.next()`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the behavior of the `this.myService.getSomeData` `Observable`.   They are not all the same.

For example if the `Observable` is a `Subject` or a `BehaviorSubject`, you will end up with multiple subscriptions with some/all not unsubscribed.  In other words a memory leak.

If it is something like the Angular `HttpClient`'s `get` `Observable`, it will initiate a network function and eventually complete on its own.  No `unsubscribe` is needed.

If you do have multiple or an unknown number of subscriptions possibly outstanding at the time of the Component destruction, you might want to try something like this:

```
s: Subscription [] = [];

ngOnDestroy() {
   s.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());
}
```

Then each time you subscribe to something do a `s.push(subscription)` and you are set.